# What is Git HEAD@{x}

Tags: git

I saw code examples using `HEAD@{1}`.

While reading about HEAD I saw the difference between `HEAD~` and `HEAD^` but what does this mean or where can I read more about the `HEAD@`?

Comment: `HEAD@{0}` is the most recent value of `HEAD`, `HEAD{1}` is what `HEAD` had before `HEAD{0}`.. `HEAD{2}` is what...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HEAD@{1}` is the reference before `HEAD@{0}` (which is the current `HEAD`).

Everything you're looking for can be found in the [gitrevisions documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). Additionally the [`git reflog` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) should be helpful too.

Comment: In addition to the gitrevisions docs, the [`git reflog` documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) should be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

Git logs every change to HEAD in what is called reflog. Run `git reflog` to see. The `HEAD@{x}` will refer to the commit in that log.